# Why calling GC.Collect is speeding things up

Tags: c++, .net, garbage-collection, swig, dispose

We have a C++ library (No MFC, No ATL) that provides some core functionality to our .NET application. The C++ DLL is used by [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to generate a C# assembly that can be used to access its classes/methods using PInvoke. This C# assembly is used in our .NET application to use the  functionality inside C++ DLL.

The problem is related to memory leaks. In our .NET application, I have a loop in my .NET code that creates thousands of instances of a particular class from the C++ DLL. The loop keeps slowing down as it creates instances but if I call GC.Collect() inside the loop (which I know is not recommended), the processing becomes faster. Why is this? Calling Dispose() on the types does not have any affect on the speed. I was expecting a decrease in program speed on using GC.Collect() but it's just the opposite.

Each class that SWIG generates has a ~destructor which calls Dispose(). Every Dispose method has a lock(this) around the statements that make calls to dispose unmanaged memory. Finally it calls GC.SuppressFinalize. We also see AccessViolationException sporadically in Release builds. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some types of object can clean up after themselves (via `Finalize`) if they are abandoned without being disposed, but can be costly to keep around until the finalizer gets around to them; one example within the Framework is the enumerator returned by `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection.GetEnumerator()`.  Each call to `GetEnumerator()` will attach an object wrapped by the new enumerator object to various private update events managed by the collection' when the enumerator is `Dispose`d, it will unsubscribe its events.  If `GetEnumerator()` is called many times (e.g. many thousands or millions) without the enumerators being disposed and without an intervening garbage collection, the collection will get slower and slower (hundreds or thousands of times slower than normal) as the event subscription list keeps growing.  Once a garbage-collection occurs, however, any abandoned enumerators' `Finalize` methods will clean up their subscriptions, and things will start working decently again.

I know you've said that you're calling `Dispose`, but I have a suspicion that something is creating an `IDisposable` object instance and not calling `Dispose` on it.  If `IDisposable` class `Foo` creates and owns an instance of `IDisposable` class `Bar`, but `Foo` doesn't `Dispose` that instance within its own `Dispose` implementation, calling `Dispose` on an instance of `Foo` won't clean up the `Bar`.  Once the instance of `Foo` is abandoned, whether or not it has been `Dispose`d, its `Bar` will end up being abandoned without disposal.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right, our abandoned object list is growing. I see a lot of memory leaks (30-40 MB) in C++ library after analyzing it with the Debug Diagnostics Tool. First thing we should do it fix the leak and then carefully check the Dispose hierarchy in our classes. Any idea what could be the reason behind an AccessViolation exception --it is only seen when GC initiates the collection automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Do you calling GC.SupressFinalize in your Dispose method? Anyway, there is nice MSDN article that explains, how to write GC friendly code - [garbage collection basics and performance hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx). Maybe it will be useful.

Comment: Yes, it calls GC.SupressFinalize.